# folding with eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm working on a project rather imposing on eclipse. I like to know if it is possible to create folding (text retractable piece) used by eclipse with methods and comment but in my case the piece of text in a method?
Sorry in advance for my English

Comment: What did you try? What do you mean?

Comment: I explained myself badly, I want to retract some of the code as we can already do with the method in order to retract the pieces to improve the readability of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, see this link: [Folding in Eclipse Text Editors](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Folding-in-Eclipse-Text-Editors/folding.html). (I found this with google)

Comment: I explained myself badly, I want to retract some of the code as we can already do with the method in order to retract the pieces to improve the readability of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
Just use a third party plugin like [Coffee-Bytes Plugin](http://kosiara87.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html).
If you are on eclipse Juno or Kepler, you need to google around for a 1.0.7 version of the jar provided in the archive.